# Переобучение. Значение метрики на трейне и на тесте

Tags: машинное-обучение

О чём может говорить факт того, что на трейте при изменении параметров лосс падает, а на валидации либо постоянен, либо совсем немного падает. Можно ли как-нибудь интерпретировать?

Пример:

```
MSE
valid: 0.07403846153846154
train: 0.16153846153846155
```

При уменьшении L2 с 0.2 до 0.1 train падает с 0.2 до 0.16. valid +- остаётся в одних и тех же пределах.

В задаче очень маленькая выборка: 115 примеров. Возможно, есть противоречивые примеры. 6 фичей числовых. Супер-маленькая выборка. 75 примеров в трейне. 35 на валидацаию.

Comment: при переобучении значение метрики на тестовых данных должно ухудшаться. При такой маленькой выборке данных трудно сказать что-то определенное. А какой алгоритм регрессии вы используете?

Comment: Обычную л1-регрессию, которая выражается в виде scikit-learn регрессии. Мне вроде удалось выбросить 4 примера, которые вносили раздор. Надо их изучить

Comment: очевидно выбросы... наверное вопрос тогда стоит удалить?

Comment: @MaxU nu, da-da. sdelal, konechno